# How to execute sh file by PHP from web page

Tags: php

#### /root/script/test.sh

```
echo 'test';
```

#### /var/www/html/sh.php

```
<?php

echo 'start'.PHP_EOL;
echo shell_exec('/bin/sh /root/script/test.sh');
echo 'end'.PHP_EOL
```

If I run the PHP at local `php sh.php`, I got `start test end`, but if I run the php from url, `http://example.com/sh.php`, I only got `start end`, the script is not executed, but if I execute `echo shell_exec('ls -al');`, it will show the list on web page.

Comment: Is the same user being used to execute both scripts?

Comment: Most probably web server won't have execute permission for the script owned by `root`. Also note `shell_exec` is disabled when PHP is running in safe mode.

Comment: I change both php and sh file owner to apache:apache, still not work, but how come `ls` work?

Answer (score 0):

Try This by using `file_get_contents`:

```
$path = file_get_contents('/root/script/test.sh');
echo shell_exec($path);
```

Comment: @Chan: than try this: echo shell_exec('sh /bin/sh /root/script/test.sh');